# "Save to Drive" button runs only on localhost webserver

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-api-js-client

I'm developing a web application that dinamically creates XLSX files available for download. I inserted the HTML/Javascript code of "Save to Drive" widget to allow users to save files also to personal gdrive account. The button runs perfectly in localhost (IIS) environment, but when I release web application on a different webserver it doesn't run (using same my account). Also connecting by another notebook (in same organization/domain) to localhost web server, the button doesn't run. It is shown regularry, but when I try to save file no actions are made (no errors message).This is the simple code of "Save to Button" using:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
                        <div class="g-savetodrive" 
                        data-src="FilesArch/Document1234.xlsx"
                        data-filename="Document1234.xlsx"
                        data-sitename="LINFA (FCA Item)">
                        </div>
```

Maybe I undervalued something like app-key, auth, client ID, but in local environment the code runs correctly.

Comment: Did you check the [Drive Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/savetodrive#troubleshooting) guide? Also, does it work on some browsers? This may have to do with your IIS more than a Drive API issue.

Comment: Thanks noogui.
I enabled CORS on my iis server but without success. The very strange thing is that the button is displayed correctly but if I try to change the google account before to open window to select destination nothing happens. 
The GDrive navigation window opens correctly but when I confirm the destination the download doesn't run and no error message are shown.
I have written for test a simple HTML page with the code of GDrive Button and the result is the same. It works if I use the browser on the web server but it does not work if I use the browser from another workstation.